# Why is a duplicate file sometimes created after editing a file?

Tags: editors, gedit, duplicate

I use gedit to modify/create files in my system, and sometimes I see that after editing, a duplicate file is created by the name of `samename~`

Just that `~` is extra. Why does this happen? Is there any significance of this file or is it okay if I delete it (I usually do)?

Comment: It's not _sometimes_... It's either _always_ or _never_, based on your settings (_Preferences > File Saving > Create a backup copy of files before saving_)

Comment: @don_crissti May be sometimes user11327 does not look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some editors backs up the original file with a suffix, usually `~` but sometimes `.bak`, when saving the new file.

Vim, for example, does this if the `backup` option is enabled. With Vim, you may also modify the suffix used for the backup files:

```
set backup
set backupext=.bak
```

See also `:help backup` in Vim.

Refer to the documentation for your particular text editor.

Comment: Old school local machine version control.  And it has saved me several times over the decades